# Highchart plugin creating different Y-axis scale on different browsers

Tags: highcharts

Highchart plugin creating different Y-axis scale on different browsers.

Where in column high chart (highchart.js), Y-axis scale varies on cross browsers for same data.

Chrome creating with scale of 200
Firefox creating with the scale of 100

**Chrome**

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxpxB.jpg)

**Firefox**

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J7kd.png)

Please let us know the reason for browser specific scaling and please suggest us the fix to show same scale on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use tickInterval in y-axis to have a fix interval on y-axis.

```
 yAxis: {
          tickInterval: 100            
        },
```

> If the tickInterval is too dense for labels to be drawn, Highcharts
>   may remove ticks.

Have a look at this documentation.

[Highchart](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickInterval)

OR

You can use tickPositioner to have it dynamically set the tick position based on min and max values. The documentation can be found [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner). and the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/)

Comment: We would like to avoid hard coding of tickInterval. Since, we are not sure about the higher data range. Is there any reasons for browser specific scaling.

Comment: You can dynamically calculate the tickInterval based on the max point value on y axis. Divide the max value with no of tick you wanted on y-axis

Comment: You can use [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner) which allows you to create function. You can define your own algorithm and calculate ticks dynamically.